# InDesign: import multiple questions from Word, one per page

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, typesetting, formatting

I'm not even sure what to search for as I googled for a while but couldn't find anything.

In a Word doc, I have a list of 300 questions.

I'm trying to create a writing journal where there is one question on each page.
In Indesign, I created a master page with a text box.

1. Is there an easy way to somehow "flow the text/questions" so that there is one on each page?
2. Should I be looking into some other software?

Comment: Does your Word document have one question on each page? You *can* maintain page breaks when placing a Word Doc into InDesign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each question is just a line or two of text, you can use InDesign's autoflow feature and get 300 pages, each with a question at the top, in under 1 minute:

- remove the text frame from the master, you don't need it with this method
- make sure the questions in your Word file are listed one after another in a continuous, paragraph-after-paragraph flow (in english, just add a single <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after each question in the Word file)
- set up the margins on the `master page` of the InDesign doc to whatever they need to be, before going further
- copy paste everything, all 300 questions on `page 1` of the InDesign doc, into a single text box
- create and apply a paragraph style to everything. use [Keep options](https://creativepro.com/keep-options-interact) under paragraph style settings to set this up so that each paragraph starts in the next frame. with this step done properly, you should only see the first question at this point, as everything else will get pushed on to display in the next steps (see image below)
- add another `page 2`
- click the bottom right handle of the text frame on `page 1` (it should look like a small, red plus sign). the mouse cursor will change
- go to `page 2`, hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and click on the page's top left edge
- with this done properly, InDesign will now auto-generate 300 pages each with a text box, each with a question at the top

[image]

Comment: I would say it’s a better idea to keep the text frame as a primary frame on the master page and then use smart-flowing. That way, you can more easily change the dimensions afterwards on all 300 pages, if you decide later on that you want to change the layout.

Comment: Different ways to approach the master page situation. There is also the option to adjust all the pages in one go at a later stage, by using the "Adjust layout" under "Margins and columns".